# real time faces bluring with pi zero

Tags: pi-zero, real-time

I would like to know if the Raspberry Pi Zero is capable of running deep learning facial recognition and blur faces in real time.

If not, what kind of portable device is able to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Not face recognition, but I have done real-time detection (were detecting faulty spots of a certain product) via OpenCV on Raspberry Pi 3B+ before. I have to admit that the performance was questionable (low fps between 5-10, high temp. etc.), however at that time the customers needs were met. Thus, I highly doubt Raspberry Pi Zero can satisfy your needs.

[Here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=248221) is some info about getting between 15-17 fps without blurring, with Raspberry Pi 4, also they mention a lightweight library to do that. It may be a good starting point for your research.